# Quasi Newton Methods Convergence

Tags: numerical-methods, convex-optimization

I am using quasi-newton(BFGS) method with wolfe line search conditions to find the optimum for a convex function. At times, when I run the code, it tends to get stuck at a point which is not optimum. I mean, I reach certain point using the quasi newton based descent direction where it's not possible to find the next point which satisfies wolfe conditions even with very small value of alpha to the range of ^-100 .

I am guessing this error may arise due to bad stopping criteria. I am using central differences to approximate the gradient, does the stopping criteria depends upon the step size of central differences?

**What should be the stopping criteria for quasi-newton method?**
Can anyone provide some suggestion about the convergence of quasi newton method?

Comment: Are you resetting your BFGS periodically? If you restart from the non optimal point does the algorithm continue? Is this a numerical issue?

Comment: I am starting with an initial guess and let the program to converge until gradient become sufficiently small.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question...

Comment: What do mean by resetting the BFGS periodically? I have not checked by restarting from the same point yet. I guess this is an numerical issue but I am unable to figure out what might be causing the problem. Can you please suggest what part might be causing numerical errors?

Comment: I think it would be interesting you show the problem you are trying to solve. Did you try higher order approximations for the gradient ?

Comment: I would advise against using central differences. One reason is that the gradients are wrong when getting close to the optimum, and you are not getting descent directions. Another reason is that they are very slow - requires $O(n)$ function evaluations. I would advise you to use automatic differentiation (google it) in your favorite language - you get exact gradients without sacrificing much speed.

Comment: At some point, the accuracy of your finite difference approximation to the derivatives will limit the accuracy that can be obtained in the solution to the optimization problem.  "Restarting" the BFGS method (setting H=I and taking a descent step) might help with this problem.

Comment: Have you tried varying the step size you use in your centered difference approximation to see what it does to the optimization iterates?

Comment: @BrianBorchers I compared the central difference values with analytical derivative and yes, its the error in the approximation that is creating the problem. I tried varying the step size also, but it needs to be changed for each problem. Is there any way to calculate accurate values of derivatives without the need of changing parameters like step size?

Comment: @BrianBorchers Sir, also can you please advice me about what should be the stopping criteria? Currently I am using |X(k) - X(k-1)|/ X(k-1) < e as one where Xk represents the current iteration values.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yes sir I tried the higher order approximations but again I need to change the step size for each problem separately.